# What kind of device do I need

Tags: ipv4, ieee-802.11

I have two devices that need to be connected over wifi and get DHCP ip addresses both of them have ethenet ports so a figured I could save some money and get a external device that receives dhcp over wifi and then gives it to them over the wire. Can I use a standard wifi router for this or do I need a different kinda of device?

Comment: This forum is really for business-scale networks, but you might find this helpful: https://www.cnet.com/uk/how-to/how-to-get-your-ethernet-only-gadgets-on-your-home-network/

Comment: If you already own the access points see if they have routing and dhcp capabilities. If so you could use one of those. If not a simple router (even "home style" would work) that hands out dhcp will work. Your computers will need to point to a gateway or router of some kind if the need to get to the internet as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: Sorry Ron. I'm the only one who mentioned "home style router" not the poster. @Micah, you could use a small business class firewall that has dhcp and routing capabilities. It would hand out DHCP addresses need route you with firewall protection.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague, but DHCP is just data, so any Wi-Fi adapter will do.  Unfortunately product recommendations are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

You need a wireless access point capable of client mode. It can connect to your existing wi-fi network and bridge between it and the wired Ethernet ports.